# Button isn't starting a new intent

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to make a register screen with some text fields for the user to type a username and a password, and the button should save the data and go back to the login screen. But when I click the register button, it doesn't go back to login screen.

I have commented where I think the error is at:

```
package com.example.gerenciadorestoqueoficial;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Cadastro extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText cadastroNome;
    EditText cadastroPassword;
    EditText cnfCadastroPassword;
    Button cadastrar;
    Button voltar;
    TextView verLogin;
    DbHelper db;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tela_cadastro);


        cadastroNome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCadastroNome);
        cadastroPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCadastroPassword);
        cnfCadastroPassword =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etConfirmarPassword);
        cadastrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);
        verLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLoginCadastro);
        voltar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVoltarCadastro);
        final DbHelper db = new DbHelper (this);

        verLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Cadastro.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        });

        voltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Cadastro.this,MainActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        // here is the button

        cadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

             public void onClick(View view) {

                String usuario = cadastroNome.getText().toString();
                String password = cadastroPassword.getText().toString();
                String cnfPassword = cnfCadastroPassword.getText().toString();

                if(password.equals(cnfPassword)){
                    long val = db.adicionarUsuario(usuario, password);
                    if(val > 0){
                        Toast.makeText(Cadastro.this, "Usuário cadastrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent irParaLogin = new Intent(Cadastro.this, MainActivity.class);   // here is the intent that is not working
                        finish();
                        startActivity(irParaLogin);
                    }else if(cadastroNome.getText().toString().length() == 0 || cadastroPassword.getText().toString().length() == 0 || cnfCadastroPassword.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(Cadastro.this, "Preencha todos os campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    }
            }
        });

        }

    }
```

It should be saying "Usuário cadastrado" after saving data with the help of SQLite and then going back to login screen, unless the passwords do not match in both text fields.

Comment: add a else bracket to the first if and then check if that comes to it. If yes then your passwords are not matching.

Comment: cadastroPassword.getText().toString().trim(); try definig like this

Comment: I added the else bracket like kunal suggested and it worked, so I updated the post since the only problem now is that the register button (cadastrar.setOnClickListener) is not opening the login screen

Answer (score 0):

```
Better u make your DBHelper Insert method like bool return type

  public boolean InsertData(String name,int cost,int sell,int profit)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Name",name);
    contentValues.put("Cost_Price",cost);
    contentValues.put("Selling_Price",sell);
    contentValues.put("Profit",profit);
    long result= db.insert("Table_B",null,contentValues);

    if (result==-1)
        return  false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

after this send your Username and Password to this method and accept it in Boolean variable....as foolows

```
 boolean isInserted = mdb.InsertData("Cake" "1kilo", 60, 50, 10);

            if (isInserted == true)

              //start your intent here
            else
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "OOps Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```